# PostgreSQL SSL full or ca verification does not work

Tags: postgresql, ssl, windows-server, qliksense

we are running a Windows Server 2019 with PostgreSQL. I want to use SSL so the connection between our database and another server within the domain is secure.

I configured the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf and provided a .cert and .key file (postgresql.conf) and the ip adress for the hostssl in the pg_hba.conf.

The other server finds the configuration and also the certificate - if the SSL seetibgs are set to "require".

When I change it to "ca" or "full" I get an error message that the certificate cant be found or is not valid.

My question(s):

- Do I need to provide a CA File aswell? I have a RootCA2015 file - is it that one? Do I maybe need to name it "root.crt" specifically? Can it be at any place as long I configure the path or does it need to be in a specific path?
- What else could be a reason a certificate is not valid in that case? Initially I got a .cer file which I converted to a .crt file with openssl.
- Is it possible to use the Trust Store of the OS directly? The certificates are installed but the other server cant find them...

Comment: The "other server" I assume will have the role of client to the database server.  But what is the nature of that client?  What connection library does it use?  Yes, it needs to trust the root which (maybe indirectly) signed the server's cert, which you usually do by providing it with the root's cert.  I have no idea who signed your server's cert, I guess it could be RootCA2015 but that would not be my first guess.

Comment: The "other server" is a Qlik Sense Server. I'm trying to create a data connection, there is a option for PostgreSQL. The certificate is signed by our own enterprise...

Comment: The client needs the root certificate so that it can verify the server's certificate.